# Newline in confirmation box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newline

I want to have two lines in my alert box

Right now I have the following:

```
<%= link_to 'back', 'history.back()', :confirm => 'Are you sure? This is my second line' %>
```

I have tried adding '\n' but it is not working, it just writes \n between my text. What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the single quotes around your confirm text are causing the `\n` to be interpreted literally. Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'back', 'history.back()', :confirm => "Are you sure? \n This is my second line" %>
```

Comment: The ":confirm" key needs to go inside the ":data" key hash now in Rails 4+

Answer (score 3):

If you want a multi-line confirm/alert statement, you will need to use double quote. 
Single quote will not convert your new line feed \n

This would work:
:confirm => "You are about to \n DELETE all tracking information.\nAre you sure?"

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

[New line in JavaScript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box) You need to stop rails from escaping the new line in the generated HTML form. Can you try `<%= link_to 'back', 'history.back()', :confirm => raw 'Are you sure? \n This is my second line' %>`

Comment: I think replacing `history.back()` with `:back` would also work here?

Comment: I just copied his code, but yeah `link_to :back` should work.

Comment: 'raw' did not work for me. I got a compile error. Replacing the single quotes for double quotes fixed my problem