# how can i show one statements to print in 3 lines using single echo statement?

Tags: php, javascript

Here is  my code

PHP

```
<?php
    $count1 = $obj->getDatef();
    $as1 = $count1 + 6;
    $startdate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($count1 . ' days'));
    $enddate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($as1 . ' days'));

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Current Timesheet period($startdate (Mon) ~ $enddate (Sun)) of 
              $pcode has been successfully Updated....!')";
    echo "</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.location='my_tm.php'";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Here it have to print like this.....

> Current Timesheet period
>
> $startdate (Mon) ~ $enddate (Sun) of $pcode
>
> has been successfully Updated....!

Comment: Use `\n` to break statement into new lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New line in JavaScript alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 0):

There are two way the most popular is to use \n at the end of your echo to break line. Or you could use 
 tag which is less efficient as it will add markup to you page.

An example would be

```
echo("im line one \n im line two\n im line three");
```

this will out put

```
im line one
im line two
im line three
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "alert('Current Timesheet period\n
             $startdate (Mon) ~ $enddate (Sun) of $pcode\n
             has been successfully Updated....!')";
```

[And here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7uRk/)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "alert('Current Timesheet period\n$startdate (Mon) ~ $enddate (Sun) of $pcode\n has been successfully Updated....!')";
```