# php echo alert message with new line '\n' not working

Tags: javascript, php, string

I have a message that I would like to show by using alert()

```
$message = "No result found for the following info:Name: ".$FullName."IC: ".$ID." in database.";
echo "<script>alert('".$message."'); window.history.back();</script>";
```

This is working but if I add a new line '\n' into the message

```
$message = "No result found for the following info:\nName: ".$FullName."\nIC: ".$ID." in database.";
```

it will not show out the pop out message. What is the problem?

Comment: look at the page source what is the html output on those lines? do you have a live link?

Comment: This might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit it to not change to newline in PHP, instead in javascript:

```
'No result found for the following info:\nName: '.$FullName.'\nIC: '.$ID.' in database.'
^                                               ^           ^      ^     ^             ^
```

**OR** by adding extra backslash: `"\\n"`.

According to Panther, also truth: use `'alert("' . $message . '")'`.

Answer (score 4):

Or use PHP_EOL

```
 $msg = 'Hello' . PHP_EOL . 'Next line';
```

Comment: nice and great answer

Answer (score 3):

Add another `\` backslash on your newlines:

```
$message = "No result found for the following info:\\nName: ".$FullName."\\nIC: ".$ID." in database.";
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VQIpsb)

Answer (score 1):

`\n` etc. aren't interpreted in single quotes, just in double quotes.

```
echo "<script>alert(\"" . $message . "\"); window.history.back();</script>";
```

OR

```
echo '<script>alert("' . $message . '"); window.history.back();</script>';
```

Comment: This will not affect the content in `$message`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: when you downvote something, you should be sure it isn't the solution. Did you try it before you downvoted? Of course it works, that's how JS interprete escaped chars like `\n, \r, \t`, etc.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did try it. Your suggestion would work if you applied it to the definition of `$message`, as yergo did in his answer. But this way `$message` is echoed verbally, including the newlines which break the javascript code.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: if in HTML, which is generated from PHP, will be `alert("whatever \n content...")`, in alert will be two lines. Doens't matter if text in alert comes from PHP or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) + [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

```
\r\n
```

and that will work as shown in the following script:

```
echo "If you view the source of output frame \r\n you will find a newline in this string.";
echo nl2br("You will find the \n newlines in this string \r\n on the browser window.");
```