# How to line break in JQuery alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do line break in alert JQuery? It should pop up like this

```
Good
Byee

alert("Good<br>Byee");
```

Is there any way to break line in JQuery?

Comment: i would try to avoid alert Boxes in most Cases because they are browser related. Most of the time it will be better to use a little bit css and html for alerts ... its alot more userfriendly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in JavaScript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 6):

This is not the `jQuery`, this is a pure `Javascript`

```js
alert('Good\nByee');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n` for line break in alert message.

```js
alert("Good\nByee");
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` character is used as newline character:

```
alert("Good\nByee");
```