# How to insert new line in input validation tooltip message? When Hover it works fine but i click send it doesnt

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I add new line in the input tooltip message . I tried `<br>, \n, &nbsp;`
but it didn't work.

```
<input type="password"  id="password" v-model="user.password" class="form-control"
 title="Must contain at least one number, one uppercase letter, one special character and at least 8 characters"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}" required>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add line break within tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips)

Comment: Can you share the full code with the bootstrap part

Comment: @Alex https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern3

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helpful to you

Just use the entity code `&#013;` for a linebreak in a title attribute.

[Add line break within tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips)

https://jsfiddle.net/cuahms2z/

```html
<form id="myform" >
  <input data-html="true"  type="password"  id="password" v-model="user.password" class="form-control"
 title="Must contain at least one number &#013;
 one uppercase letter &#013;one special &#013; character and at least 8 characters"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}" required>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Itried here , but it doesnt works :((        https://jsfiddle.net/y25dorp3/

Comment: @gesha You used the html tag not the uml code, as Mansi wrote

Comment: @gesha Please check once , https://jsfiddle.net/cuahms2z/

Comment: @Mansi unfortunately, is this because of chrome ? i am using chrome browser, tried both in mac and windows, :((

Comment: @gesha I tried in firefox ,IE and chrome. it's work in this three browser in windows

Comment: when i hover it works fine. but when i click send it doesnt. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Mansi in your example when you click Submit there is not a line break at all.

Comment: This only works for the tooltip on hover. It does not work for the error message after submitting the form. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806922/798634) for adding line breaks to error message.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I have created an issue for this at mdn/mdn https://github.com/mdn/mdn/issues/114

---

I researched a bit about this and found also 2 other SO Questions one were unanswered and the other had a really bad answer.

- [setCustomValidity message styles on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206405/setcustomvalidity-message-styles-on-multiple-lines)
- [Create line breaks in oninvalid message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656246/create-line-breaks-in-oninvalid-message)

Then I found [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145) article and it helped me to understand the case a bit better and I wrote my own customValidityMessage.

```
var input = document.getElementById('inp');
input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Must contain at least" + "\n"+ "one" + "\r" + "number one uppercase \n letter,\n one special \n character and at least 8 characters");
}
```

The [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) said that the parameter for `.setCustomValidity()` is a DOM String and a DOM String corresponding to JS String

> A DOMString is a sequence of 16-bit unsigned integers, typically
> interpreted as UTF-16 code units. This corresponds exactly to the
> JavaScript primitive String type. When a DOMString is provided to
> JavaScript, it maps directly to the corresponding String.

so I thought it should be easy possible to insert inside the string `'\n'` or `'\n'`. So I tried as you can see in the example below and it is interpreted but inside the message there is still no line break.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inp');
input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Must contain at least " + String.fromCharCode(13) + " one " + String.fromCharCode(67) + " number one uppercase \n letter,\n one special \n character and at least 8 characters");
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input id="inp" data-html="true" type="password" id="password" v-model="user.password" class="form-control"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I didn't found a solution for this sadly but I thought my attempts can be helpful to solve this isssue so I decided to write it here as a summary of my perceptions.

Comment: Itried here , but it doesnt works :((        https://jsfiddle.net/y25dorp3/

Comment: @gesha you mean when clicking send? The tooltip works fine as you can see when you hover over the password.

Comment: yes when i hover it works fine. but when i click send it doesnt. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This works now! When form is submitted the error message contains newlines where there is a "\n".

Answer (score 0):

Putting enter makes lines change.

```html
<input type="password"  id="password" v-model="user.password" class="form-control"
 title=" · Must contain at least one number, 
 · one uppercase letter, 
 · one special character and
 · at least 8 characters"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}" required>
```

Comment: Itried here , but it doesnt works :((        https://jsfiddle.net/y25dorp3/