# Highscore Alert - next line and Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a quiz on my website and use local storage to save the last scores.

I like to print them in an alert and it works well, but I like to print every score in a new line.
How is this possible?

Also, is it possible to put a title (or a text above the scores) in the alert?

```js
function highscore() {
    var lastscores = localStorage.getItem("lastscores.sort().reverse()").split("\n")
}
```

[image: Example of an alert]

Comment: You need to use the new line control code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box

Comment: use backslash to split

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert2   simple example here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code, I first save some score in an array, then retrieve it from `localStorage` and then split it to array, because it's string so parse it to integer and then sort it in descending order. if you want ascending order to replace `b-a` to `a-b`

```html
  localStorage.setItem("lastscores",[18,44,5,7]);
  var title = "Your HighSocres";

function highscore() {
  var lastscores =   
  localStorage.getItem("lastscores")
              .split(',')
              .map(function(s){
                      return parseInt(s); //convert to integer(Number)
                 })
              .sort(function(a,b){
                      return b -a //sort decending)
                    })
             .join('\n')
var toAlert = title + "\n" + lastscores
    alert(toAlert)
}
```

for title you can do something like :

```
const allString = "Your socres \n" + lastscores
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I need to place the title code?

Comment: @Nils-HendrikWelk if my answer help or solve your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **join** function instead of **split** for instance:

```
const scores = [1,2,3]; 

alert(scores.join("\n"))
```

Comment: Like this:  function highscore() {
    var lastscores = localStorage.getItem("lastscores.sort().reverse()").join("\n");
}
It is the same result :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
alert(scores.toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, '\n'))
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. Can you please implement it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function highscore() {
var lastscores = localStorage.getItem("lastscores.sort().reverse()").replace(/ *, */g, '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's the same result :(