# Problem displaying error to the user from AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, error-handling

Am using AJAX code whereby I handle errors form the backend code.. All is working well except that I want to alert the errors individually to the user in a numbered list

**Expected Output**

```
1. Please insert a valid phone number
2. Please insert your email
3. Please insert a valid passport number
```

**AJAX code handling errors**

```
error: function(data) {
                //Unblock the spinner
                $.unblockUI();
                var errors = '';
                for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                    errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '<br>';
                }
                //Alert each error individually
                alert(errors);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommended that you should be using a `for loop` instead of `for in`. [See why here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/1571106)

```
error: function(data) {
  //Unblock the spinner
  $.unblockUI();
  var errors = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < data.responseJSON.length; i++){
    // Remove the "(i+1) + '. ' + " if your json response already contains that part.
    errors += (i+1) + '. ' + data.responseJSON[i] + '\n'; // <-- Notice how the br tag is changed to a new line
  }
  alert(errors)
}
```

I also changed the `<br>` tag to a `\n` as alerts don't support html tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me from the question, whether you want a

1. multiline alert message or
2. multiple alert dialogs as the
   output,

but in case 1) is true, you should use newline ("\n") instead of br tag - see [New line in JavaScript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box) and the code could look like:

```
var i = 1,
    errors = '';

for(datos in data.responseJSON){
    errors += i + '. ' + data.responseJSON[datos] + '\n';
    i++;
}

//Alert each error individually
alert(errors);
```

If 2) is what you need, you should call alert() for each error message