# Why are \n characters not showing as newlines in an alert when the value is pulled from an html data attribute?

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple confirmation alert with vanilla javascript. I want to provide the alert message using a `data-confirm` attribute placed in the html (as in the below runnable snippet). But the newline characters I enter into the message text (i.e. the value of the `data-confirm` attribute) are displayed literally as "\n" rather than a new line. This issue does not arise when the exact same characters are entered into an alert directly (i.e. not drawn from the value of a `data` attribute).

Running this snippet illustrates the issue. The first alert shows the newline properly and the second does not.

```js
confirmationElem = document.querySelector(`[data-confirm]`);
confirmationElem.addEventListener('click', get_confirmation);

function get_confirmation(e) {
  confirmationMessage = e.target.getAttribute('data-confirm');
  alert(confirmationMessage);
  alert("Line one\nLine two");
}
```

```html
<div data-confirm="Line one\nLine two">click for a message</div>
```

This SO post does not answer my question: [New line in JavaScript alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841452/new-line-in-javascript-alert-box) ... nor does any other I've found.

There seems to be some issue based on the fact that I am getting the string value for the message from the `data` attribute using `.getAttribute('data-confirm')`.

Questions:

- Why do the two alerts in the above snippet display newlines differently?
- How can I make an alert that gets the message value from a `data` attribute display newlines properly?

Comment: The html attribute is not a string literal. You cannot use a backslash as an escape character in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML does not use the backslash as an escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references), that's why it shows up as a literal backslash. Instead, you need either a literal newline, a [numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) or a [named character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```js
function get_confirmation(e) {
  const confirmationMessage = e.target.getAttribute('data-confirm');
  alert(confirmationMessage); 
}
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll(`[data-confirm]`)) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', get_confirmation);
}
```

```html
<div data-confirm="Line one\nLine two">message with a backslash</div>

<div data-confirm="Line one
Line two">message with a linebreak</div>

<div data-confirm="Line one&NewLine;Line two">message with &amp;NewLine;</div>

<div data-confirm="Line one&#10;Line two">message with &amp;#10;</div>

<div data-confirm="Line one&#xA;Line two">message with &amp;#xA;</div>
```